# lazy loading of images on my webpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

after some research and after I've asked some questions, I've realized the following: jQuery plugin Lazy Load (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) doesn't work on Safari and even not on Firefox.

I've just tested their demo.

Please you need to use Firebug, and see how all the images are loaded at once at the beginning and then loaded again on scroll (so you actually have double downloading).

Could you give me a solution how to implement the mashable.com images lazy layout ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
 <img alt='some_text'  _src="img_url" class='lazyLoad'>
  // please note i have added underscore character before 'src'

jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('.lazyLoad').each(function(){
           var _elm= jQuery(this);
           _elm.attr('src',_elm.attr('_src'));

           //on DOM ready loop through each 
          //image with class=lazyLoad and add src attribute to it.
       })
});
```

Comment: mhm, so the only way is to change the original code ? This is a bit problematic for me, since I don't have just a static page.

Comment: are you looking for something like: on initial load display only those images which exist is visible area of window and load more images when scroll happens. like youtube does.??

Comment: A good example is mashable.com . But the point is that I cannot change the original html code (i.e. _src) as you suggest. From what I can see the only way is to change the original code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not working for me on FF 3.6 on Mac, I created my own plugin that works fine called **JAIL (Jquery Asynchronous Image Loader)**

Try to check the [project homepage](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail) and let me know your thoughts. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It is the part of automatically removing image src which does not work anymore. This is due to changes in how modern browsers load images. Version 1.5 released Dec 23, 2009 provided alternative where you must alter HTML and store image url in `original` attribute. I renamed it recently to `data-original`to be HTML5 friendly. I also updated to [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) which better explains how to use it.